# Entropy of $n$ topological excitations in the classical XY-model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, topological-phase

I am dealing with Kosterlitz-Thouless phase transitions in the classical XY-model and trying to derive a formula for the entropy as a function of the number of vortices. In most textbooks, the entropy associated with a single vortex is shown to be

$S=k_{B}ln{(\frac{L}{a})^{2}}$,

by simply counting the number of possible configurations in which the vortex center can be located on the lattice, namely $(\frac{L}{a})^{2}$, with $L$ and $a$ standing for the system size and lattice spacing, respectively. Should I therefore barely consider the number of ways I can place a certain number of vortices on the lattice with a binomial coefficient, or is there some extra contribution to the entropy due to having more than one vortex?

Comment: I suppose that when vortices are close to each other, they will interact and possibly merge with each other. This is probably what happens when one is close to the phase transition. So they can be treated as independent only when they are few. But I am not an expert in BKT transition.

Comment: This question could fit on the new [Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/)